# ESLint create-config is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

I have been trying to install ESLint into my new project, but I have constantly been getting this error no matter how I install it. I've followed all the guides I've found and every time I get the error that create-config doesn't exist.

I have tried changing the version of ESLint that is installed, as well as making a new npm project, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the [getting started guide](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/getting-started)?

Comment: I did, it didn't work.

Comment: Which node and npm versions are installed on your system? You can check it by running `node -v` and `npm -v`

Comment: Node is v18.12.1 and npm is 8.19.2

Comment: Looks fine... Which command are you trying to run, that causes the error?

Comment: I've tried eslint --init, npm init @eslint/config and I've tried using the VSCode extension which also gives an error pop-up that says eslint.createConfig can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Debian 12. I had eslint installed globally via `npm install -g eslint`, but it wasn't in my PATH and so did not work as intended. First I had to add my user's global node bin directory to my path ($HOME/.local/share/node/bin), but after resolving that I ran into the same issue you did, I presume.

```
~/Documents/some-project$ npm init @eslint/config
sh: 1: create-config: not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/$USER/Documents/some-project
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-config

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/$USER/.npm/_logs/2023-11-10T16_09_14_958Z-debug-0.log
```

Fixing this issue required adding yet another directory to the path, as it turned out that create-config was in $HOME/.npm/_npx/bin/

Once both of these directories were in my PATH, the configuration setup for eslint finally worked. Here is a line you can add to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc to add both path additions.

`export PATH=$HOME/.npm/_npx/bin/:$HOME/.local/share/node/bin:$PATH`

You'll have to start a new bash session for this to take effect. Additionally, some linter integrations may not invoke through bash, and so may need to be configured separately to modify the PATH environment variable.